# deflect the ball in same incoming direction

Tags: velocity, collision

```
ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y
```

this above statement makes the ball deflect ,similar to pong game but ..

I am stuck in making the ball deflect the same direction as the incoming direction ..

Answer (score 2):

Negate the x velocity as well, as in `ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x`.